# Creating a new column based on two old columns in a data frame

Tags: r

```
data <- data.frame(foo = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1),
                   bar = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0))
```

Hi, Here I am having a data frame with two columns foo and bar. I want to create a new column Complete, based on foo and bar data.

- If foo and bar is zero then complete should be 0.
- If foo is one and bar is 0 then complete should be one.
- If bar is 1 and foo is 0 then complete should be two.

For example.

```
foo   bar complete
0     0   0
1     0   1
0     1   2
```

**Edit:**

If `foo==1` and `bar==1` then `NA`.

Comment: In real data, do you have just 2 columns, like foo and bar?

Comment: `c(0, 1, 2, NA)[c(2*bar + foo + 1)])`

Answer (score 3):

Following suit, using `NA` when both columns are 1.  Start with the row sums.  If any of them are 2 (the number of columns), replace it with `NA`.  Then multiply that by the `max.col()` value.

```
rs <- rowSums(data)
cbind(data, complete = max.col(data) * replace(rs, rs == 2, NA))
#    foo bar complete
# 1    0   1        2
# 2    1   0        1
# 3    0   0        0
# 4    0   0        0
# 5    1   1       NA
# 6    0   0        0
# 7    0   1        2
# 8    0   0        0
# 9    1   0        1
# 10   1   1       NA
# 11   1   0        1
```

If you don't wish to assign new objects, you can use a local environment or wrap it up into a function:

```
local({
    rs <- rowSums(data)
    max.col(data) * replace(rs, rs == 2, NA)
})
# [1]  2  1  0  0 NA  0  2  0  1 NA  1
```

Comment: Just like python pandas , I like it ~:) +1

Comment: Nice, would this extend to *n* columns?

Comment: @zx8754 - I think we could make it extend to `n` columns by using `rs == ncol(data)` or `rs > 1`, something like that.  We can control `max.col` with the `ties.method` argument.

Answer (score 3):

If an algebraic approach is sought, we can try one of the lines below:

```
with(data, 2L * bar + foo + 0L * NA^(bar & foo))
with(data, 2L * bar + foo + NA^(bar & foo) - 1L)
with(data, (2L * bar + foo) * NA^(bar & foo))
```

All return

> ```
> [1]  2  1  0  0 NA  0  2  0  1 NA  1
> ```

#### Explanation

The expression `2L * bar + foo` is treating `bar` and `foo` as digits of a binary number. The difficulty is to return `NA` in case of `foo == 1 & bar == 1`. For that, `bar` and `foo` are treated as logical values. If both are `1`, i.e., `TRUE` then `NA^(bar & foo)` returns `NA`, otherwise `1`.

If one operand of an expression is `NA` so is the overall expression. So, there are several possibilities to combine `NA^(bar & foo)` with `2L * bar + foo`. I wonder which is the fastest.

#### Benchmark

So far, 7 different approaches have been posted by

- [d.b](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286220/3817004)
- [Balter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286229/3817004)
- [PoGibas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286275/3817004)
- [Rich Scriven](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46286394/3817004)
- Frank (in chat)
- [user 20650 in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46286118/creating-a-new-column-based-on-two-old-columns-in-a-data-frame/46293443#comment79543464_46286118)
- [Uwe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46293443/3817004)

The OP has supplied his sample data as type `double`. As I have seen remarkable different timings for `integer` and `double` values on other occasions, the benchmark runs will be repeated for each type to investigate the impact of data type on the different approaches.

#### *Benchmark data*

The benchmark data will consist of 1 million rows:

```
n_row <- 1e6L
set.seed(1234L)
data_int <- data.frame(foo = sample(0:1, n_row, replace = TRUE),
                       bar = sample(0:1, n_row, replace = TRUE))
with(data_int, table(foo, bar))
```

> ```
>    bar
> foo      0      1
>   0 249978 250330
>   1 249892 249800
> ```

```
data_dbl <- data.frame(foo = as.double(data_int$foo),
                       bar = as.double(data_int$bar))
```

#### *Benchmark code*

For benchmarking, the `microbenchmark` package is used.

```
# define check function to compare results
check <- function(values) {
  all(sapply(values[-1], function(x) all.equal(values[[1]], x)))
}

library(dplyr)
data <- data_dbl
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  d.b = {
    vect = c("0 0" = 0, "1 0" = 1, "0 1" = 2)
    unname(vect[match(with(data, paste(foo, bar)), names(vect))])
  },
  Balter = with(data,ifelse(foo == 0 & bar == 0, 0,
                            ifelse(foo == 1 & bar == 0, 1,
                                   ifelse(foo == 0 & bar == 1, 2, NA)))),
  PoGibas = with(data, case_when(foo == 0 & bar == 0 ~ 0,
                                   foo == 1 & bar == 0 ~ 1,
                                   foo == 0 & bar == 1 ~ 2)),
  Rich = local({rs = rowSums(data);  max.col(data) * replace(rs, rs == 2, NA)}),
  Frank = with(data, ifelse(xor(foo, bar), max.col(data), 0*NA^foo)),
  user20650 = with(data, c(0, 1, 2, NA)[c(2*bar + foo + 1)]),
  uwe1i = with(data, 2L * bar + foo + 0L * NA^(bar & foo)),
  uwe1d = with(data, 2  * bar + foo + 0  * NA^(bar & foo)),
  uwe2i = with(data, 2L * bar + foo + NA^(bar & foo) - 1L),
  uwe2d = with(data, 2  * bar + foo + NA^(bar & foo) - 1),
  uwe3i = with(data, (2L * bar + foo) * NA^(bar & foo)),
  uwe3d = with(data, (2  * bar + foo) * NA^(bar & foo)),
  times = 11L,
  check = check)
```

Note that only the result vector is created *without* creating a new column in `data`. The approach of PoGibas was modified accordingly.

As mentioned above, there might be speed differences in using `integer` or `double` values. Therefore, I wanted to test also the effect of using integer constant, e.g., `0L, 1L`, versus double constants `0, 1`.

#### *Benchmark results*

First, for input data of type `double`:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval   cld
>        d.b 1687.05063 1700.52197 1707.72896 1706.48511 1715.46814 1730.62160    11     e
>     Balter  287.89649  377.42284  412.59764  452.75668  458.21178  472.92971    11    d 
>    PoGibas  152.90900  154.82164  176.09522  158.23214  165.73524  333.48223    11   c  
>       Rich   67.43862   68.68331   76.42759   77.10620   82.42179   89.90016    11  b   
>      Frank  170.78293  174.66258  192.85203  179.69422  184.55237  333.74578    11   c
>  user20650   20.11790   20.29744   22.32541   20.81453   21.11509   34.45654    11 a    
>      uwe1i   24.86296   25.13935   28.38634   25.60604   28.79395   45.53514    11 a    
>      uwe1d   24.90034   25.05439   28.62943   25.41460   29.47379   41.08459    11 a    
>      uwe2i   25.21222   25.59754   30.15579   26.29135   33.00361   47.13382    11 a    
>      uwe2d   24.38305   25.09385   29.46715   25.41951   29.11112   45.05486    11 a    
>      uwe3i   23.27334   23.95714   27.12474   24.28073   25.86336   44.40467    11 a    
>      uwe3d   23.23332   23.65073   27.60330   23.96620   29.53911   40.41175    11 a
> ```

Now, for input data of type `integer`:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval   cld
>        d.b 591.71859 596.31904 607.51452 601.24232 617.13886 636.51405    11     e
>     Balter 284.08896 297.06170 374.42691 303.14888 465.27859 488.19606    11    d 
>    PoGibas 151.75851 155.28304 174.31369 159.18364 163.50864 329.00412    11   c  
>       Rich  67.79770  71.22311  78.38562  77.46642  84.56777  96.55540    11  b   
>      Frank 166.60802 170.34078 192.19833 180.09257 182.43584 350.86681    11   c
>  user20650  19.79204  20.06220  21.95963  20.18624  20.42393  30.13135    11 a    
>      uwe1i  27.54680  27.83169  32.36917  28.08939  37.82286  45.21722    11 ab   
>      uwe1d  22.60162  22.89350  25.94329  23.10419  23.74173  47.39435    11 a    
>      uwe2i  27.05104  27.57607  27.80843  27.68122  28.02048  28.88193    11 a    
>      uwe2d  22.83384  22.93522  23.22148  23.12231  23.41210  24.18633    11 a    
>      uwe3i  25.17371  26.44427  29.34889  26.68290  27.08276  47.71379    11 a    
>      uwe3d  21.68712  21.83060  26.16276  22.37659  28.40750  43.33989    11 a
> ```

For both `integer` and `double` input values, the approach by *user20650* is the fastest. Next are my algebraic approaches. Third is `Rich`s solution but three times slower than the second.

The type of input data has the strongest impact on `d.b`'s solution and to a lesser extent on *Balter*'s. The other solutions seem to be rather invariant.

Interestingly, there seems to be no remarkable difference from using `integer` or `double` constants in my algebraic solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a named vector (`vect` in this example) and lookup values from that vector using `match`

```
vect = c("0 0" = 0, "1 0" = 1, "0 1" = 2)
unname(vect[match(with(data, paste(foo, bar)), names(vect))])
# [1]  2  1  0  0 NA  0  2  0  1 NA  1
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this, some more efficient depending on how many conditions you have.  But a basic way is:

```
data$New_Column <- with(data,ifelse(foo == 0 & bar == 0, 0,
                         ifelse(foo == 1 & bar == 0, 1,
                         ifelse(foo == 0 & bar == 1, 2, NA))))

#   foo bar New_Column
#1    0   1          2
#2    1   0          1
#3    0   0          0
#4    0   0          0
#5    1   1         NA
#6    0   0          0
#7    0   1          2
#8    0   0          0
#9    1   0          1
#10   1   1         NA
#11   1   0          1
```